# Getting RGB colors

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, rgb

I want to get the rgb value of colors that are given as strings (accent 1, accent 2, ..., accent 6).
[This](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC215681.gif) is a table I got which describes each color visually. I want to get each of those six values in format like this: #ff0000.

Comment: What do you mean visually identify the RGB values ?

Comment: You can visually see that accent 3 is green.

Comment: How are you displaying those colours in the boxes? Do you have a `Color` object?

Comment: I don't. That's what I'm asking. How to display the colors from the image as #ff0000. The image is from msdn. It's not mine.

Comment: short way .. go to `mspaint` and check out the RGB values for the green you see

Comment: Question : The table is yours ? Or you just get the string of color (for example: "accent 1").
If I look at the table, the colors aren't some default name-value type. 
The provider don't get you values name/color ?

Comment: Wpf. I thought it doesn't matter.

Comment: If would be easier to help you with a question about a specific piece of code, as the question is formulated now it's really hard to figure out what you really want help with.

Comment: JinDave obviously had no trouble understanding what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Accent 1: #4f81bd
Accent 2: #c0504d
Accent 3: #9bbb59
Accent 4: #8064a2
Accent 5: #4bacc6
Accent 6: #f79646
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look at how to get the [Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) object from these controls (do you have access to the controls? *Hopefully* there will be a way to get (and probably set) the color of the selected color). If you have a list of these controls, you could create a `Dictionary<string, YourColorControl>` in this control and use this code;

```
 Dictionary<string, YourColorControl> _colors = new Dictionary<string, YourColorControl>(); //find a way of filling this dictionary

string colorStr = "Accent 1";
if(!_colors.ContainsKey(colorStr)
    throw new Exception("No color with this name");

byte red = _colors[colorStr].R;
byte green = _colors[colorStr].G;
byte blue = _colors[colorStr].B;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try ready to use solution like [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDropDownColorPicker.aspx)